# How to upgrade our ADT bundle offline when google pushes its update to ADT bundle

Tags: android, adt

I am using the ADT bundle 22.3 . Which is complete offline zip bundle that I have downloaded directly from the android.com . But now they have pushed update to ADT bundle 22.6 so after downloading the ADT bundle 22.6 zip how can I upgrade it with my old ADT 22.3 offline?

I am dealing with offline bundles not online because I don't have that much bandwidth so I can download it online. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install it offline, you have to specify the zipfile as a local archive in the "Install New Software..." section.  Then it's just a matter of browsing to the zip.

Comment: But just a heads up...when I did that, I was getting some weird things, like seeing "BuildId" as the ADT build version after upgrading.  If you experience issues, let me know.

Comment: Well, to play it safe, you might want to backup the ADT you have on an external drive.  Then do your upgrade.